# How to wrap text under the label in a list

Tags: lists

I have the following list

```
\section{Basic Notions and Definitions}
 Most of the material in this section is standard and is intended to provide 
 background information.
\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,label=\thesection.\arabic*]
   \item Throughout, $R$ will stand for a noncommutative and associative ring with 
    identity and all rings considered as such. Our modules are unitary right modules 
    unless otherwise specified. Also, the letters $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, 
    $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ are used for the set of natural numbers, the 
    ring of integers, the ring of integers modulo $n$ ($n$ is a positive integer 
    greater than $1$), and the field of rational numbers, respectively. For given 
    subsets $A$ and $B$ of a set $X$, $A\setminus B = \lbrace x\in A \mid x\not\in B 
    \rbrace$, and we use $|X|$ to denote the cardinal number of $X$.
 \end{enumerate}
```

which produces what is shown in the screenshot below
[image]

I have two questions:

1. How to wrap the text under the labels (**1.1.1**, **1.1.2**, and so on) of the list?
2. How to indent all the labels of the list to be under the number of the section precisely? In other words, I don't want any label to come before the number **1.1** of the section. Can the parameter `leftmargin` solve this?
3. How to start a new line ***in the same item*** with a left indentation (as usual) but without the unwanted vertical spacing produced?.

Comment: Try with these options: `\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,label=\thesection.\arabic*,wide,leftmargin=0pt,labelindent=0pt]`

Comment: Thanks. This worked.

Comment: I Edited the question. I just added a new question (question #3).

Comment: Your 3rd requirement is not clear from the example. Moreover, don't just expand the question as people answer it... it may change the entire setup and nullify existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to set the option `wide=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\section{Basic Notions and Definitions}

Most of the material in this section is standard and is intended to 
provide background information.

\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries, label=\thesection.\arabic*, wide=0pt]

\item Throughout, $R$ will stand for a noncommutative and associative 
ring with identity and all rings considered as such. Our modules are 
unitary right modules unless otherwise specified. Also, the letters $
\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ are used for 
the set of natural numbers, the ring of integers, the ring of integers 
modulo $n$ ($n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$), and the field of 
rational numbers, respectively. For given subsets $A$ and $B$ of a set 
$X$, $A\setminus B = \lbrace x\in A \mid x\not\in B\rbrace$, and we use 
$|X|$ to denote the cardinal number of $X$.

\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `labelindent=0pt` is also needed as @Warner mentioned above for question 2.

Comment: I Edited the question. I just added a new question (question #3).

Comment: @HusseinEid - "labelindent=0pt is also needed" -- are you sure?

Comment: Of course not. Anyway, I apologize. I will post a new question.